# Does a DataSets DataTable inherit structure when no records exist?

Tags: c#, dataset, sql-server-ce

I'm hooking a DataSet up to a SQL CE 3.5 database and chasing down an exception (nullref). I think the issue may be caused by an empty DataSet but I'm struggling to understand the way in which the structure of a DataTable works.

If I populate a DataSet against a table where only the structure exists, no records have been added, what is the standard behavior? Is a DataTable of matching structure instantiated or is the DataSet left empty? (assuming this Database contains just the one table I'm connecting to in this case).

EDIT: Cheap example

Database "Contacts" with just 1 table "MyContacts". It has four fields, ContactID, Name, Phone, Email (int, nvarchar x3)

```
            DataSet data = new DataSet()
    SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(); 
            SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyContacts ", connection);
            SqlCeCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Fill(data, MyContacts);
            return data;
```

What happends if the table exists (its structure is present) but there are no records?

Comment: Depends on what you call and how you call it. And on the preconditions. As always, a little code could help a lot.

Comment: I don't think I could really demonstrate the issue through code. It simply importing Data into a DataSet using a SqlCeDataAdapter. I'm trying to understand the behavior when a table exists but has 0 records. Hows does the DataSet (and by extension the DataTable) handle itself in this situation?

Comment: If you populate a DataSet from a stored procedure that returns no rows then the DataTable will be created but with no rows. Therefore the behaviour for an empty table will be the same.

Comment: Right, thanks. This might mean I'm looking in the wrong place which is good news (I think). I did assume that a DataTable still inherits structure even if no records exists but I wanted to be clear.

Comment: +1, according to the [DbDataAdapter.Fill Method (DataSet, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y4b211hz(v=vs.80).aspx): _If a command does not return any rows, no tables are added to the DataSet, and no exception is raised._.  Real world example shows the contrary... Intriguing, isn't it?

Comment: I'm using DevExpress components and I'm guessing those are responsible for throwing a wobbily. I reckon they have a problem attaching themselves to empty data. I had suspected this was the case.